# ImportError: No module named youtube_dl

Tags: python

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
import youtube_dl

print('Hello, please insert the url of the video that you want to download.')

downloadUrl = input()

ydl_opts = {}
with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
        ydl.download([downloadUrl])
```

Hey, um, the program overall seems to be working just fine when it opens with the cmd, but when I try to run it with F5 in the IDLE, it crashes with the error: ImportError: No module named youtube_dl. I have it installed and tried re-installing it aswell. This particular program works fine, but trying to write anything else using this module brings this error up even in the cmd window.

Comment: How did you install the `youtube_dl` module, and what directory was it installed in?

Comment: I think I installed it through cmd using pip install and it used to work fine. It's installed in the site-packages folder.

Answer (score 17):

Reinstalling it with the following pip command worked for me.

CMD: `pip install --upgrade youtube-dl`

Jupyter Notebook: `!pip install --upgrade youtube-dl`

Answer (score 6):

What worked for me was

```
pip3 install --upgrade youtube-dl
```

Answer (score 0):

check if those packages are present in your local ie `C:\Users\yourname\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages`

1. youtube_dl
2. youtube_dl-2019.10.16.dist-info
3. pafy
4. pafy-0.5.4.dist-info

else

```
pip install pafy
```

then copy paste these files from `C:\Program Files\Python37\Lib\site-packages` to the local